# How did Jaco Pastorius get nicknamed 'Jaco'?

Tags: jaco-pastorius

The famous electric bassist was born as John Francis Anthony Pastorius III.

Is it known how he got nicknamed Jaco?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jaco was a big fan of baseball and often watched games. He got his nickname from [Jocko Conlan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocko_Conlan). He was first nicknamed 'Jocko' after the aforementioned player, but later, he received a note from a friend of his friend who had misspelled 'Jocko' to 'Jaco', because he didn't know how it was spelled.

<sub>I first saw this on an article about Jaco's life (which I cannot find right now), but wikipedia states pretty much the same.</sub>

Comment: If I recall correctly, Jaco himself tells the anecdote in [an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZSa9niKKE4), and I think he mentions that the fellow who called him “Jaco” was a Frenchman, although I don’t recall his name.

Comment: the name of the french man who misspelled Jocko is Alex Darqui.